# Clean url for static and dynamic pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I have a website with a mixture of static pages without variables (ex: about.php) and some dynamic pages (ex: searchresults.php?a=1&b=2)

Right now my .htaccess allows for the static pages to show, but not the dynamic ones. Everything I've tried to do to make the dynamic pages work, however, breaks the clean URLs for the static pages.

```
RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I would like the final result to look like this:

```
http://example.com/about.php -> http://example.com/about
```

and

```
http://example.com/searchresults.php?a=1&b=2 -> http://example.com/searchresults/1/2
```

Is what I'm looking to do possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Firstly, you'll need to change your rule to strip the extension. Currently, you have two rules that match anything (meaning that the second will never trigger), and the second rule doesn't have a condition.

Secondly, your search rule will need to be specified explicitly.

Your `.htaccess` file should now look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite the search page

RewriteRule ^searchresults/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ searchresults.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA,L]

# Allow requests without php/html extensions

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked out perfectly! Just one question... my relative links to my .js and .css files on the server (which are in an included header.php) didn't work on the search page. Is there any way to fix that or should I just stick with an absolute URL?

Comment: If you are using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyles.css">`, for example, you can simply prepend a forward slash so it becomes relative to the root of the domain: `href="/css/mystyles.css"`

Answer (score 0):

Try below line of code for your htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule aboutus/$               about.php   [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule searchresults/(.*)/(.*)/$           searchresults.php?a=$1 & b=$2   [NC,L,QSA]
```